# I downloaded the mssql tools for mac os, but it says "sqlcmd: command not found"

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, bash, macos

I'm trying to connect to the MS SQL server outside of the container on my mac terminal.
I followed these instructions:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker

and I'm able to access the sqlcmd command inside the container. However, when I follow the instructions for the command outside of my container:
sqlcmd -S 10.3.2.4,1401 -U SA -P ''

It won't let me enter the command sqlcmd, and it says:
"-bash: sqlcmd: command not found"

I have a feeling it might be a path issue, did anyone else run into this issue on their mac?

Comment: Were you able to connect to database from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

To run this command(sqlcmd) from you mac you need to have this tool installed on your mac. To install sqlcmd on your mac you can follow this,

**Install the tools for Mac El Capitan and Sierra**

/usr/bin/ruby -e “$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)”

brew tap microsoft/mssql-preview https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-preview

brew update

brew install –no-sandbox msodbcsql mssql-tools

Here is the detailed instruction on howto :-

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/04/03/sql-server-command-line-tools-for-mac-preview-now-available/

Comment: For the production (non-preview) release: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2017/05/16/sql-server-command-line-tools-for-macos-released/